# Android: TimePicker without a dialog

Tags: android, widget

I would like to show a TimePicker without a Dialog. I put this into my layout file, but it shows up empty:

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/ui_dialog_alert_msg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

Comment: Share the complete layout file and corresponding activity.. what ur saying can't happen .

Comment: Use Hierarchy View to determine where you are going wrong. Here is an example of using `TimePicker` without a dialog: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/TimePicker

Comment: My bad. It's a stupid question.

Comment: would you mind posting a solution?